# pointer to a vector: getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm getting the segmentation fault in the following code. Could you please help me to figure it out? In the following code, it prints "ok here". Once it deallocates the memory, it shows the segmentation fault. But why ? any solution ?

Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Cube
{
public:
    char *str;

    Cube(int len)
    {
        str = new char[len+1];
    }
    Cube(const Cube &c)
    {
        str = new char[strlen(c.str) + 1];
        strcpy(str, c.str);
    }   
    ~Cube()
    {
        delete [] str;
    }
};

void foo(vector <Cube> *vec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char in [] = "hello !!";
        Cube *c = new Cube(strlen(in)+1);
        strcpy(c->str, in);
        vec->push_back(*c);
        cout << "ok here" << endl;
        delete [] c;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector <Cube> vec;

    foo(&vec);  
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: if you use `new[]` you must use `delete[]`

Comment: Have you tried using gdb to find the line that is failing?  Seems like the problem is that you're delete[]-ing the str variable when it is a char *.

Answer (score 4):

You have not followed [the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three):  `Cube` does not implement a correct copy assignment operator.  As others have mentioned, you have also mismatched `new[]` with `delete`, which can only end in tears.

That said, you don't need to use pointers or explicit dynamic allocation for any of this.  You should replace your usage of `new char[]` with `std::string` and don't allocate any `Cube` objects on the heap.  In a well-written C++ program, `new` should be used rarely and `delete` should almost never need to be used.

This program does no explicit dynamic allocation, has the same result as you expect from your program, but is correct.  Note how much cleaner code is when you don't worry about dynamically allocating or explicitly destroying things yourself!

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Cube {
    std::string str;
    explicit Cube(std::string const& s) : str(s) { }
};

void foo(std::vector<Cube>& vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(Cube("hello !!"));
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Cube> vec;
    foo(vec);
}
```

Make sure that you have [a good introductory C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

You are `delete`ing an array of `Cube`s here:

`delete [] c;`

But you didn't allocate an array here:

`Cube *c = new Cube(strlen(in)+1);`

It should be just:

`delete c;`

Answer (score 0):

```
delete [] c;
```

should be

```
delete c;
```

Aside from that, the `Cube` class itself is dubious. Better use a `std::string` instead of a c-style string.

Answer (score 0):

You used

```
delete [] c;
```

If c was allocated like this:

```
Cube * c = new Cube[3]; //3 for example
```

THEN delete [] c would be appropriate.  In this case, you should omit the [].